# what to do if a computer gets a blue screen when trying to install windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, acer-aspire

What might be the reason why I get blue screen when I try to install windows xp. on a laptop. Specifically an Acer aspire laptop with AMD Processor. 
What do I do to make it work. Its probably not the Cd, because I've tried it on other computer and it works.

Comment: Have you been able to read what the BSOD says?

Comment: Are you upgrading or doing a clean install?  Are you installing while in a current windows install or booting from the CD?

Comment: @daisetsu:booting from the Cd, trying to install xp with windows 7 RC installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the BSOD you will usually see a specific STOP message in all caps.  Google the exact wording of it. Also maybe look up the [STOP code](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/Windows-XP-Blue-Screen-Death-STOP-Codes-t43519.html).

Answer (score 1):

blue screens are often (but sadly, not always) informative.  Posting what the error is can help us resolve the issue.

Most frequently I see errors due to controller driver compatibility.  I would suggest visiting the manufacturer web site and downloading the controller driver and then slipstreaming it into a new install CD using a product like nLite - www.nliteos.com

It could also be hardware issues - defective RAM and the like.  But I would first let us know what the BSOD says and probably try slipstreaming the drivers second.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen BSOD's caused by malfunctioning USB devices, overheating processors, bad memory, and bad hard drives. Your BSOD is probably caused by hardware malfunction since it happens during the installation of windows.

The Stop codes can be useful... sometimes... if not, try this:

Make sure the CPU fan is spinning freely.

The BIOS sometimes has a health monitoring section that shows CPU temp and hardware error logs that can give you some hints to the problem.

Unplug all non-critical usb devices.

Test your RAM with Memtest (comes with most linux live CD's)

Check the S.M.A.R.T status of your hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Try to incorporate fresh drivers into installation disk using something like http://driverpacks.net/